# save multiple textbox data from Kinect to one text file

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am new to C# programming and have started building an WPF app using the Kinect. I have managed to track a skeleton and display each joints X & Y coordinates in text boxes, but i want to save all the data to one text file on my desktop for analysis. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/) provides a mechanism to save the skeleton stream.

If you want to roll your own -- the data is just a bunch of objects, containing 3 points.  Simply store the points, as they come in, to a `List` and then output the data to a file using [XML Serialization](https://www.google.com/search?q=xml%20serialization%20c#).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to do it. I've got all the text boxes displaying on screen using the following code, but can't get my head around how to save to file from here

Comment: TextBox1.Text = Head;
            TextBox2.Text = ShoulderCenter;
            TextBox3.Text = ShoulderLeft;
            TextBox4.Text = ShoulderRight;
            TextBox5.Text = ElbowLeft;
            TextBox6.Text = ElbowRight;
            TextBox7.Text = WristLeft;
            TextBox8.Text = WristRight;
          Etc